# Splitting output of subprocess into list/array and finding specific string inside the list/array. (python)

Tags: python, string, split, process

I'm looking to check if a process is running by name using subprocess to Popen "powershell ps | findstr processname" and do something if it's running/not running. I don't want to accomplish this using psutil.

so far this is the code I've came up with.

```
import subprocess
import sys

p = subprocess.Popen(['powershell.exe', 'ps | findstr chrome'], 
stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = p.stdout.read()
s = output.split()

chrome = "chrome"
for _ in s:
    if chrome in s:
        print("chrome running")
    else:
        print("chrome not running")
```

This doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know how to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import subprocess
import sys

p = subprocess.Popen(['powershell.exe', 'ps | findstr chrome'],
stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = p.stdout.read()
s = output.split()

chrome = b"chrome"

if chrome in s:
    print("chrome running")
else:
    print("chrome not running")
```